# Vmware View & PCoIP Host Card

Tags: windows, remote-access, vmware-view, pcoip

Does anyone know what the performance will be with or without a host card on a laptop running a vmware view client to a server which is 50-100m away on LAN Gigabit. 
The specs say that it can handle 60fps @ 1080p but is this true with a soft client like vmware view? I would like to use it for CAD/CAM software on a remote server via laptop but have no idea what the performance will be like.

Comment: Clarify, you have a gigabit point to point circuit? You have a Gigabit LAN hooked to an Internet connection? What's the latency?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I have A to B Gigabit LAN in our test LAB. Latency is <1ms

Comment: This seems relevant: http://www.unidesk.com/blog/adjusting-vmware-view-pcoip-video-intense-applications I think you will just need to test this to get an acceptable answer though, and bandwidth will be more of a problem than video performance.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff Yes however thin client with host card is limited to 20mbps. So i don't know if this limit can be lifted..

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff By the way the link you posted is thin client without hostcard. Thats why the crappy performance.

Comment: Well, just based on the numbers... 20Mbps should be enough to stream 1080p video twice over... it should be alright. I certainly would lab this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCoIP at that bitrate will handle CAD/CAM fine - your issue will be the virtual GPU's ability to render the display in the first place.

Comment: It will be from a Quadro6000 via host card. No virtual GPU.